# Multiple Where clause using same columns SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have table like this :

```
user_id    field_id    value  
1          1           toto  
2          1           tata
2          2           tata Job
```

`user_id` is the id of my users, `field_id` is the id of the information about the user `(name, job, etc.)` and value is the value.

I use a searchBar in `HTML/PHP` with 2 fields : 'name' and 'job'.
When someone search user using this two fields I need to retrieve the user id that matches these two conditions.

My question is :
How to get in `SQL` all `user_id` that match with two condition in one like this:

```
(field_id=1 and value=tata) AND (field_id=2 and value=tata's Job)
```

Thank you and have a good day !

Comment: Well first you find a good book or tutorial on _How to code SQL_

Answer (score 1):

SQL executes the `WHERE` logic for each row, not for the entire set.  And fields cannot have more than one value.  So, you need to use an `OR` statement instead of an `AND` to capture both conditions:

```
Select   User_Id, Field_Id, Value
From     YourTable
Where    (field_id = 1 And value = 'tata') 
Or       (field_id = 2 And value = 'tata Job')
```

Comment: they search a user where field_1 ( eg the name ) is Tata and field_2 ( eg profession ) is `builder'. you search any user named tata regardless of proffession and any builder regardless of name

Comment: @Aツ I'm not following - what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select user_id
from t
where (field_id = 1 and value = 'tata') or (field_id = 2 and value = 'tata''s Job')
group by user_id
having count(distinct field_id) = 2;
```

Comment: Gordon?? `value='tata's Job'` Woops

Comment: This seems overly complex for the query they're describing

Comment: the `where`clause should be: `where (field_id=1 and value='tata') OR (field_id=2 and value='tata''s Job')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` statement, for example: Your table name is `users`

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE field_id IN (1,2) AND `value` IN ('tata','tata\'s Job')
```